# How to update mongodb collection with ssh from a shell script?

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to update a mongoDb collection via ssh from a shell script but getting the below error :

> MongoDB shell version: 2.6.4
>   connecting to: localhost:27017/b2b_tempdb
>   2017-12-05T11:04:51.153+0000 SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Below is the full command :

```
ssh -n happy@localhost  " mongo --host localhost:27017  --authenticationDatabase admin b2b_tempdb --eval 'db=db.getSiblingDB( \"b2b_tempdb\" ); db[\"b2b_tempdb.activity.preferences\"].update({},{ $set: {'codeId':\"happy.l2l-09l2l121\"} }, {multi:true})' "
```

Kindly help me in getting it resolved . 
Thanks in advance for the help .

Comment: Why not you are using 'MongoDB Compass' . If you are using SSH. Are you using 'Local' or 'Remote' Database.

Comment: Not allowed to use any separate product here in the project . am trying to connect to a remote machine where MongoDb is installed . Thanks

Comment: what is your O.S environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me this works fine

```
ssh mongodb.domain.com "mongo --eval='db.getSiblingDB(\"testi\").empty.update({},{\$set:{key:1}},{multi:true})'"
```

The catch is `\` before $ because otherways shell will "expand" that $set "enviroment variable", what of course don't exists.

Comment: As per OP the error shows that he is using "localhost".

Comment: You can ssh to localhost and use localhost as host in mongo... No problem. So, my aswer works fine even I replace that `mongodb.domain.com` with `localhost`.